# .NET Core dockerize: build from project directory instead of solution directory

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi, docker-build

My project's directory structure is as follows:

```
FiinGate
|── Fiingate.sln
├── src
│   ├── FiinGate.Api
|   |   ├── FiinGate.Api.csproj
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── .dockerignore
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── FiinGate.Application
│   │   ├── FiinGate.Api.csproj
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── FiinGate.Infrastructure
│   │   ├── FiinGate.Infrastructure.csproj
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── FiinGate.Core
│   │   ├── FiinGate.Core.csproj
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── FiinGate.Domain
│   │   ├── FiinGate.Domain.csproj
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── FiinGate.Localizer
│   │   ├── FiinGate.Localizer.csproj
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── FiinGate.Templates
│   │   ├── FiinGate.Templates.csproj
|   |   |── ...
```

Here is my Dockerfile (generated from Visual Studio):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Api/FiinGate.Api.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Api/"]
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Application/FiinGate.Application.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Application/"]
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Core/FiinGate.Core.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Core/"]
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Domain/FiinGate.Domain.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Domain/"]
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Infrastructure/FiinGate.Infrastructure.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Localizer/FiinGate.Localizer.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Localizer/"]
COPY ["src/FiinGate.Templates/FiinGate.Templates.csproj", "src/FiinGate.Templates/"]

RUN dotnet restore "src/FiinGate.Api/FiinGate.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/FiinGate.Api"
RUN dotnet build "FiinGate.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FiinGate.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FiinGate.Api.dll"]
```

From `FiinGate.Api` folder, I opened `cmd` and run command:

```
docker build -t fiingate:latest .
```

And I got the following result:

[image]

I need to jump into `FiinGate` folder, and run command:

```
docker build -t fiingate:latest -f /src/FiinGate.Api/Dockerfile .
```

It works for me, but in my opinion, it is not convenient because it is not possible to build right in the project directory, but must go to the parent directory, and must always pass the `f` parameter to indicate the dockerfile.

I think I have to fix the dockerfile, but I searched a lot with no desired results. Looking forward to your help!

**EDIT**

I created a docker-compose.yml file in the same place with dockerfile:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  fiingate-api:
    image: fiingate.api:latest
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: src/FiinGate.Api/Dockerfile
```

And just only run command:

```
docker compose build
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to build solution you have to provide all of the necessary assets (source code of all the projects), that's why your build context should always be `src` or `FiinGate` directories.

You can build docker file from `FiinGate.Api` project, but you have to provide build context
this way:
`docker build -t fiingate:latest ../../`

You can also pass ../ parameter as your build context (it would be src folder):
`docker build -t fiingate:latest ../`

But it would be needed to edit Dockerfile to remove src prefixes in `COPY` directives.
Alternate approach is to create script (e.g. bash script if you are on Linux machine) to automate.